# Windows clearcase view mapped drives disappear

Tags: clearcase

We have Clearcase version  9.x is running with Linux host. We have started experiencing the view disconnected issues on post-reboot of the user systems ( which are running with Windows pro 10 & windows ClearCase client 8.x). The view mapping drives show as disconnected and we need to re-map the view drives to fix it each time the system reboots. Some cases the view shortcut alone disconnected from the ClearCase explorer and we need to add the view shortcut again to map the drives. The default view drive M: shows, as disconnected in few systems, starting the ClearCase services and adding view shortcuts again, helps here. And few other systems with same configuration working fine without any issues.

I have a few questions on this, 
Am I missing anything specific with Windows say like patching, Anti-virus etc 
Is the issue exist & common with Windows 10 operating system
How the mapping issues can be fixed, I am looking for some solutions which can be tested

Kindly suggest if you come across this issues

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the drive M:\, thus us directly linked to the ClearCase MVFS service: make sure the "Credentials Manager Service" service is set to run automatically

[image: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sites/default/files/support/swg/rattech.nsf/0/1d8d7d639e61745585257321005e068c/Content/0.416.gif]

Check the MVFS (for ClearCase 9.0) is [properly installed](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/install-or-uninstall-mvfs-windows): that will enable the dynamic views.

Regarding the shortcuts, check "[Mapping an automatic view root directory to a drive letter](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mapping-automatic-view-root-directory-drive-letter)": they should be `subst` command, which you [can make persistent across reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots)

But if those `subst` involve *dynamic* views, then again, the MVFS service needs to be correctly started, or those drive letters won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the albd is not started by the time the user logs in, this delays the start of the credential manager service. The fast-logon optimization can allow the user to in before services start.

If the views you're using are ***not*** local, you can decouple the credential manager service from its dependency on the albd service, and this could help.

> ( which are running with Windows pro 10 & windows clearcase client 8.x).

You need to upgrade to 9.0.1.x. ClearCase 8 has not been supported for (exactly) 2 years. If your hosts are running Windows 10/1909, you will need to update to 9.0.1.9 as that is the version that has been tested with 1909. Also, the MVFS "network provider" information does not survive a windows "feature update" install as that install is really a full OS install folloed by settings migrations, and MS's migration still leaves something to be desired.

You may want to do the upgrade via the "clean install" method of:

1. Uninstall ClearCase 8.0.x & reboot
2. Navigate to C:\ProgramData\IBM and remove the Rational.preserve* directories.
3. Navigate to \Windows\System32\Drivers and ensure that MVFS*.sys files are no longer present
4. Install ClearCase 9.0.1.9

ClearCase 9.0.1.8+ changed the MVFS from a 2-part (MVFS + MVFS Storage Filter) to a 1-part (MVFS only) driver configuration. We have seen reports of the old MVFS drivers not being completely removed on upgrade. In the worst cases, the old MVFS driver files were both present alongside the new MVFS driver, and all 3 were somehow loaded. This caused post-upgrade blue screens.

Comment: I am trying with installation of IM : 1.8.2 &  Clearcase : 9.0.1.4 and keep getting errors during install phase -  Error during "install" phase:

  Failed to extract zip microsoft.vc2010.x86 9.0.1000.0000-9-0-1-D170517. File C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\microsoft.vc2010.x86.iu_999.999.999.2144800458\vcredist_x86.exe already exists.

Comment: That would be a different question entirely. But I'd start with the classics, including erasing the contents of the temp directory and disabling AV during the install

Comment: ClearCase 9.0.1.9 is installed successfully after disabling protection tools  and mapping are done.  Under observation now